# SQL, How to use temp table and join multiple table

Tags: sql, vb.net

Actually, I am using GridView at vb.net. this is the sql in the datasource.

```
SELECT SE.shipperID
      , SE.sName
      , SE.consigneeID
      , SE.conName
      , SE.agentID
      , SE.aName
      , SEDetail.bolId
      , SE.masterBOLno
      , SE.coloaderBOLno
      , SE.NumOBOL
      , SE.polName
      , SE.podName
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR ,SE.onboardDate ,111)
      , SUM(SEDetail.quantity)
      , SUM(SEDetail.totalSize)
      , SUM(SEDetail.totalWeight)
  FROM SE
       INNER JOIN SEDetail ON  SE.id = SEDetail.bolId
 WHERE  SE.id = SEDetail.bolId
 GROUP BY SE.shipperID, SE.sName, SE.consigneeID, SE.conName, SE.agentID,  
       SE.aName, SE.masterBOLno, SE.coloaderBOLno, SE.NumOBOL, SEDetail.bolId, 
       SE.polName, SE.podName, SE.onboardDate
```

I want use the TemplateField to add 3 column , but GridView can not use multiple datasource

```
column 1.  count(SEDetail.containerId) (where  b.SEDetail.containerId between 1 and 5 )
column 2.  count(SEDetail.containerId) (where  b.SEDetail.containerId between 6 and 10 )
column 3.  count(SEDetail.containerId) (where  b.SEDetail.containerId = 11 )
```

So, how to use the temp table or another way to group up to one statement.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what flavor of SQL you are using but could you not add the following to your select statement:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN b.SEDetail.containerId BETWEEN 1 AND 5
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS column1
SUM(CASE WHEN b.SEDetail.containerId BETWEEN 6 AND 10
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS column2
SUM(CASE WHEN b.SEDetail.containerId = 11
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS column3
```